# Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with the name 'HeaderCntrl' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have written an angular js program and I have written the controller in a different file but I am getting the error saying that controller is not registered. can someone let me know why i am getting this.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>The angular book libraty</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper" ng-controller="HeaderCntrl">
<span class="logo pull-left">{{appDetails.title}}</span>
<span class="tagline pull-left">{{appDetails.tagline}}</span>
<div class="nav-wrapper pull-left">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Book</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kart</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the controller code, that is written in the separate js file.

```
var HeaderCntrl = function($scope){
    $scope.appDetails = {
        title : "BookKart",
        tagline : "The collection of a million books"
};
}
```

Comment: have you registererd your controller like angular.module('myApp').controller('HeaderCntrl', HeaderCntrl );

Comment: `ng-app` attribute is empty?

Comment: You missed controller file to add in html file

Comment: He missed a lot of stuff especially the guide "how to create my first AngularJS app".

Comment: @lin Well i was following a guide and the above code was from it. I guess the guide is outdated

Comment: Yep, looks like a Angular 1.0.1 guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following an old module for reference without being aware of it and the app was working fine in the guide I was using, I guess it is deprecated now. I used following code to get the proper output.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>The angular book libraty</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span class="logo pull-left">{{ title }}</span>
<span class="tagline pull-left">{{tagline}}</span>
<div class="nav-wrapper pull-left">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Book</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kart</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the external js file I used for the controller is as follows.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "BookKart";
    $scope.tagline = "We have a million book with us";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

order of injected js file is wrong

change this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

this demo is your post. just change order of injected file.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/19PXgGydYYDDj1hBzO2P?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is *just* a function. You need to use a module to create it. An example from [ng docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

And then

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
  {{ greeting }}
</div>
```